# Magento 1.7: I can't stop reindex process

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, reindex

I'm trying to separate magento back end and front end in 2 nodes. I follow the HOW-TO on magento site. Now I have two installation of magento that work properly. My problem comes when  magento start reindex process. It doesn't stop, it's in pending state since friday (5 days). 
I try to stop it by removing all locks file in /var/locks folder and restarting apache, but nothing has changed. Now I can't restart it because magento throw me an exception because reindex is in progress and I can't install any extension.

How can I restore the state of reindex process?

Comment: do you have any errors logged in var/log? assuming error logging is enabled

Comment: **In the frontend:** 2014-07-29T13:52:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /var/www/domain/htdocs/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1239
2014-07-29T13:52:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Division by zero  in /var/www/domain/htdocs/test/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/Libmemcached.php on line 395

**In the back end:**
2014-07-23T13:11:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /var/www/domain/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1239

Answer (score 1):

Check the table `index_process`, delete the locks from there and also from `var/locks` and try again.
I would recommend indexing from `php cli > shell/indexer.php`

Also, increase your execution time value from the `.htaccess`

`#php_value memory_limit 64M

php_value memory_limit 128M

php_value max_execution_time 18000`

Comment: I haven't locks files, in the .htaccess I have **php_value memory_limit 256M, php_value max_execution_time 36000** and in the index_process table all the index are in _pending_ status except catalog_product_flat is in _require_reindex_ status

Comment: Try reindexing using shell

Comment: thanks for attention. I tried to reindex using shell, reindex finish without error. I check index status on index_process table, all indexes are in pending status. But when I open index page on magento admin, all indexes are in processing status and I can't start reindex (error: Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.)